# pass state in IO action

Tags: haskell, state

I'm parsing file line by line and want to perform some action depending on what every line contain. Some of these actions change state of object and some require to print current state.

```
--code
data Adder = Adder { 
  cur :: Int, 
} deriving (Show)

initAdder :: Adder
initAdder = Adder 0

main = do
  [fname] <- getArgs
  input   <- readFile fname
  mapM_ process (lines input) 

-- file to read-------------------------
+1
-4
print
*45
+6
-5
print
-----------------------------------------
```

Question is how should i write function process to be able to pass same object of type Adder and sometimes perform IO actions (print) or just change state and go on? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to understand is that `IO` does not mean state.  For that, there's the `State` monad in the `mtl` package.  If you need to manage state and `IO` at the same time, this indicates that you want to combine two different kinds of effects together, which hints at the `StateT` monad transformer.  You could use it something like

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Control.Monad.State

-- The same state data type
data Adder = Adder { cur :: Int } deriving (Eq, Show)

-- Some helper functions for doing math on Adders
add :: Int -> Adder -> Adder
add x (Adder cur) = Adder (cur + x)

-- Note that sub x y === y - x
sub :: Int -> Adder -> Adder
sub x (Adder cur) = Adder (cur - x)

mul :: Int -> Adder -> Adder
mul x (Adder cur) = Adder (cur * x)

-- Just an alias to reduce typing and errors
type App a = StateT Adder IO a

process :: String -> App ()
-- If the line starts with an arithmetic operator, use the appropriate function to modify the current state
-- Here, I'm using readMaybe to safely convert the value to an Int, doing nothing if the value can't be parsed
process ('+':val) = maybe (return ()) (\x -> modify (add x)) $ readMaybe val
process ('-':val) = maybe (return ()) (\x -> modify (sub x)) $ readMaybe val
process ('*':val) = maybe (return ()) (\x -> modify (mul x)) $ readMaybe val
-- If the line is "print", then just print the current state
process "print"   = do
    -- Get the current state
    Adder cur <- get
    -- Since we're using the StateT transformer, have to use liftIO to perform IO actions
    liftIO $ print cur

-- A simple app that executes a sequence of statements with state
runApp :: [String] -> IO Adder
runApp fileLines = execStateT (mapM_ process fileLines) (Adder 0)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (fname:_) <- getArgs
    input     <- readFile fname
    runApp $ lines input
```

Granted, this code could be a lot shorter if you just used `Int` as your state instead of `Adder`.  You wouldn't need the helper functions and `process` could be written as

```
process :: String -> App ()
process ('+':val) = maybe (return ()) (\x -> modify (+x)) $ readMaybe val
process ('-':val) = maybe (return ()) (\x -> modify (subtract x)) $ readMaybe val
process ('*':val) = maybe (return ()) (\x -> modify (*x)) $ readMaybe val
process "print"   = get >>= liftIO . print  -- Shortened this to a one-liner too
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew there must be a way to combine IO and State

Comment: @Alexander Whenever you want to combine the behaviors of two monads (usually `IO` and another, monad transformers are a good tool to reach for.  They're by no means the only solution (and not necessarily the best either, many layers of transformers can hurt performance), but once you understand them they can be very useful.  For most of the really useful monads all have transformer variants which allow you to stack them arbitrarily, and with a nice class system you can write your function agnostic of the actual implementation of your app's transformer stack.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simplified to the ground version of this program without use of State monad and transformers, since i'm not comfortable with them yet. Maybe it will be useful to Haskell newbies such as i am.

```
main = do
  [fname] <- getArgs
  input   <- readFile fname
  process 0 $ lines input

process :: Int -> [String] -> IO()
process _ []      = return ()
process n (x:xs)
  | head x == '+' || head x == '-' = do
    process n' xs
  | head x == 'p' = do
    print n
    process n xs
  | otherwise     = return ()
    where
      n' 
        | head x == '+' = n + (read (tail x) :: Int)
        | otherwise     = n - (read (tail x) :: Int)
```